# Select in navbar dropdown form

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a website and am currently a bit stuck (using flask and bootstrap).

Currently implementing a navbar and I am trying to create a drop-down form to login from. In this form, I want to have a select drop-down box. I have implemented the box and the form, but when I click on the box it closes instantly. Found some JavaScript on GitHub that supposedly should fix the issue, but it does not. (Assuming the JS code does not match with my program might be the issue. I know nothing about JS)

Edit 1: Included bootstrap links.

The Issue (GIF):
https://gyazo.com/67c6bf57629993c2596b2396eeb8713c

My Navbar:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link  
      rel="stylesheet" 
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
      integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" 
      crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link 
      rel="stylesheet" 
      href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/style.css') }}"
    />
    <title> {% block title %}Home{% endblock %} </title>

  <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/custom.js') }}"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Start of navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
        <!-- Logo & Placeholder name -->
        <img src="https://opgg-static.akamaized.net/images/medals/challenger_1.png?image=q_auto:best&v=1" alt="Logo" width="30" height="24">
        Placeholder
      </a> 
      <!-- Navbar collapse -->
      <button
        class="navbar-toggler"
        type="button"
        data-toggle="collapse"
        data-target="#navbar"
      >
      
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
        
        <!-- Start of the nav-bar tabs -->
        <ul class="navbar-nav">

           <!-- Nav-bar re-sizing if the browser or screen is small -->
           <li class="nav-item dropdown" id="my_dropdown">
               <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                  Login
                </a>
                
                <!-- The login form in a drop-down menu -->
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">

                   <!-- This is the bootstrap-select for region in the login form -->
                   <select class="form-select" aria-labelledby="Default select example">
                    <option selected> Select region</option>
                    <option select> EUW</option>
                    <option select> EUNE</option>
                    <option select> NA</option>
                    <option select> China</option>
                   
                  </select>

                  <!-- Form-class for the sign-in -->
                  <form class="px-4 py-3">

                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="summoner_name">Summoner Name</label>
                      <input type="summoner_name" class="form-control" id="summoner_name" placeholder="Summoner Name">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="password1">Password</label>
                      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password1" placeholder="Password">
                    </div>
                    <!-- Remember me checkbox -->
                    <div class="form-check">
                      <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="dropdownCheck">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="dropdownCheck">
                        Remember me
                      </label>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Sign in -->
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" href="/">Sign in</button>
                  </form>
                  
                  <!-- Login - Create new account | Forgot password -->
                  <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="/sign-up">Create new account.</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Forgot password?</a>
                </div>
                
            <!-- Search function start -->
              </li>
            <!-- Select region, search function -->
            <form method="POST">
              <select class="form-select" aria-labelledby="Default select example">
                <option selected> Select region</option>
                <option select> EUW</option>
                <option select> EUNE</option>
                <option select> NA</option>
                <option select> China</option>
              
              </select>
              <!-- To be implemented, search function -->
              <li>
                <input type="text" placeholder="test">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="sumbit">Search  </button>
              </li>
          </form>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container">
      {% block content %}
      {% endblock %}

    </div>
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The problem seems to be with the css, pls include css otherwise its impossible to solve the problem, as the dropdown works the way it should in the snippet above...

Comment: Added the CSS. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The previous JavaScript checked if a user clicked either on a specific target or somewhere else, since the select element itself isn't the specific target the dropdown closes.

The following is a working example where the dropdown menu closes if a user clicks on an element that isn't a sibling of a parent with class `no-close`.

```
<style>
  .open {
      display: block !important; 
  }
  #login-drop {
      display: none;
  }
</style>
<script>
  document.addEventListener("click", e => {
      const target = e.target;
      if (!Boolean(target.closest(".no-close"))) {
          document.getElementById("login-drop").classList.remove("open")
      }
  })
</script>
<input class="no-close"
       type="button"
       value="login"
       onclick="document.getElementById('login-drop').classList.add('open')"></input>
<div id="login-drop" class="no-close">
  <select>
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
    <option>C</option>
    <option>D</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

You can alter it as necessary, but the important point are:

- set the `login` button and dropdown menu to class `no-close`
- Trigger `open_dropdown()` with `onclick` with the login button